# Background not working in a setter

Tags: wpf

I am trying to make a simple resource dictionary for styles but the Background property is throwing an "Invalid Token". Setting the background directly in the property works fine. Here is an example using a button style:

```
<Style x:Key="ExampleButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="DarkGrey" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="30" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Grey" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you show the xaml for the button you are trying to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the value need to be Value="Gray" and not Value="Grey"

or try to set your own "Shade of Gray",  Value="#B2AFAF"

Comment: It does bud, it's called resharper :P.

Comment: In my VS2010 and 2012, when i type Value= it shows me a list of brushes.